# Dot animation on pagination CSS using :not selector to exclude first and last child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have been working on a new style of pagination with a dot animation on the numbers but not the first and the last child of the pagination but not sure what I'm doing wrong.

If I remove the following lines the animation works but not the first and last child elements.

```
.pagination a:before:not(:last-child),
.pagination a:before:not(:first-child),

.pagination a:hover:before:not(:last-child),
.pagination a:hover:before:not(:last-child),
```

**Code**

```css
.paging-navigation {
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 margin: 40px auto;
 padding-top: 30px;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-box-pack: center;
 -ms-flex-pack: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
.pagination { font-family: Arial, Verdana, Sans-serif; line-height: 38px;}
.pagination a,
.pagination a:link,
.pagination a:visited,
.pagination a:active,
.pagination .current {
 position: relative;
 padding: 8px 12px;
 margin: 0 1px;
 font-size:14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #444444;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.pagination a:before:not(:last-child),
.pagination a:before:not(:first-child),
.pagination a:before {
 content: '\2022';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 text-align: center;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: 300ms ease;
}
.pagination a:hover:before:not(:last-child),
.pagination a:hover:before:not(:last-child),
.pagination a:hover:before {
 content: '\2022';
 position: absolute;
 top: -20px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 text-align: center;
 opacity: 1;
}
.pagination a:hover,
.pagination span.current { color: #444444; font-weight: bold; }
.pagination .current:before {
 content: '\2022';
 position: absolute;
 top: -20px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 text-align: center;
}
.pagination .extend  { color: #919191; float: right; font-size: 11px; line-height: 35px;}
```

```html
  <nav class="navigation paging-navigation">
    <div class="pagination loop-pagination">
      <a class="prev page-numbers" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-fw"></i>Previous</a>
      <a class="page-numbers" href="#">1</a>
      <a class="page-numbers" href="#">2</a>
      <span class="page-numbers current">3</span>
      <a class="page-numbers" href="#">4</a>
      <a class="next page-numbers" href="#">Next<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-fw"></i></a>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

What am I doing wrong? Might be I am using the `:not` selector in a wrong method or not as CSS standards but when I validate the CSS using the W3C Validator it validates 100%

Comment: Maybe you should swap `not` and `before` like `a:before:not(:last-child)` `a:not(:last-child):before`. Also, `something, something:not()` equals to `something`! Maybe you want write `a:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):before`

Comment: Still, does not work. I want to avoid the dots animation on first child and last child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove dot on previous and next link then you don't need to target them with pseudo classes. just use a:not(.prev)  and a:not(.next) and you will hopefully accomplish your task

Comment: Silly me I didn't notice that class names. I will accept your answer if you can just post code so that it will be helpful for others in case they look for something similar.

Comment: Got it using `.pagination a:not(.prev):not(.next):before`